# How to implement route planer to find the optimal route in iOS for more than two consecative destinations

Tags: ios, iphone, dictionary, mapkit

**Scenario:** I need to develop a logic in an App where I might get more than two Addresses and I need to find the optimal route, the order and start the direction to all addresses.

**Example:** Let's assume I am having 4 addresses like A, B, C and D. Let' assume the optimal  route (concerning distance and if its possible traffic) would be

`Current location --> C --> B --> D --> A`.

**Limitation:** The method

```
+ (BOOL)openMapsWithItems:(NSArray *)mapItems launchOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

documentation says:

If you specify the `MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeKey` option in the launchOptions dictionary, the `mapItems array must have no more than two items in it`. If the array contains one item, the Maps app generates directions from the user’s current location to the location specified by the map item. If the array contains two items, the Maps app generates directions from the location of the first item to the location of the second item in the array.

1. How do I find the order?
2. How do I start the direction to the optimal path which contains all consecative destinations?

   - I am expecting the solution using only iOS
   - If its possible from iOS 6 (must not be)
   - If there is a better solution with the help of third party framework Eg. Googl Maps for iOS then how?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See the [Travelling salesman problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem). The most accurate way is to get the driving distance from all points to all points (back and forth, to account for one-way routes if necessary). Then to loop through every permutation to find the shortest route. It's pretty intense, especially if you have a lot of locations. If you don't need driving distance, and have a set of LatLongs, you can work out the straight line distance without using external services.

Comment: @Tom Thanks for the good start.